# Running unit tests on controllers fails before started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

Just started to learn Ruby and Rails and currently have I created a controller to authenticate a user and provide a token. It works perfect doing monkey testing (clicking around and postman), but when doing testing with this command:

```
rails test
```

will even this test fail:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should be true" do
    assert true
  end

end
```

It will output this in the terminal:

```
Error:
UserControllerTest#test_should_be_true:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT
NULL constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", 
"updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2017-03-18 11:11:35.973444', '2017-03-18 11:11:35.973444', 980190962)
```

Can't see what the problem should be. Because if I try to create a unit test inside the a ActiveSupport:TestCase will it fail with same output.

Can anyone tell me why it does this?

Obs!
If you need more information about the user controller just post a comment. Thanks.

Edit

In my applicationcontroller have this code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  require 'json_web_token'
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception


  protected
  def authenticate_request!
    if !payload || !JsonWebToken.valid_payload(payload.first)
        return invalid_authentication
    end

    load_current_user!
    invalid_authentication unless @current_user
  end

  def invalid_authentication
    render json: { error: 'Invalid Request'}, status: :unauthorized
  end


  private
  def payload
    auth_header = request.headers['Authorization']
    token = auth_header.split(' ').last
    JsonWebToken.decode(token)

  rescue
    nil
  end

  def load_current_user!
    @current_user = User.find_by(id: payload[0]['user_id'])
  end

end
```

My test settings under config/environments/test.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true

  config.eager_load = false
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=3600'
  }

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
end
```

Comment: You're (somehow) trying to save a user with no email before your test cases are run. That's why the error. Check the settings of your test framework.

Comment: @31piy I have pasted the settings for the test environment. Is that the right config?

Comment: It cannot be determined with the pasted code. Is your code hosted on Github or some kind of publicly accessible repo?

Comment: Here is a copy of the repo: https://github.com/mcboman/jwt-so-help

Comment: @31piy https://github.com/mcboman/jwt-so-help/issues forgot to tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably in your `test/fixtures/users.yml`. There are two users without attributes:

```
one: {}
# column: value
#
two: {}
# column: value
```

When minitest starts it attempts to create two users with empty fields and it violates not null constraint for `email`. Try to either remove these lines or populate them with correct values